# Getting all rows from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get all rows from table1.

```
class Table1Model
  def getAll
    @data = table1.select(%q{id})
  end
end
```

It gives undefined local variable or method `table1'...

So how can I tell rails that it should look for table1 in my development database?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to know rails use ActiveRecord to handle the query, edit, delete of database records.

And rails takes MVC as the standard principle.

For example, you will have a table called "products" in your database if you have a class called "*Product*". You just need to call `Product.all` or `Product.to_a` in rails 4.0.0.

If you don't want to use any of above but deal with some legacy system. You can use: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select * from table1")`
However, this way is not recommended.

Comment: Ok, if I use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select * from table1") how could I have associative array in result ? res[:id] does not work.

Comment: You would need to do something like: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select * from table1").to_a` then you should be able to access the items in the array and the associations on each item.